# How to get all words after first white space in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table whose rows has names' contents as follow :

```
Name
------------------------
NIWEMUKIZA GRACE
NIYIRORA MARY REINE
Muganga jean ema samuel
```

I want to get only the word part before first white space and the rest words after first space.

Output :

```
Lastname     |   Firstname
-------------+-------------
NIWEMUKIZA   |    GRACE
NIYIRORA     |    MARY REINE
Muganga      |    jean ema samuel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either (or both) [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) and [`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), or [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). Both of them are used below:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 1) AS `first_name`,
  SUBSTRING(`name`, LOCATE(' ', `name`)) AS `last_name`
FROM
  `names`
```

Gives us:

```
first_name | last_name
----------------------
NIWEMUKIZA | GRACE
NIYIRORA   | MARY REINE
Muganga    | jean ema samuel
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92e94e/5